# Object oriented programming: Is there an other way to create objects

Tags: oop

Which do you think is better in terms of good coding.

When I creating an object I will use new keyword to create an instance of that class.

```
var objA = new A()
```

If I create an object by creating a static method name CreateA in A class and create an object of A by calling CreateNewA or CreateInstance instead of new A().

```
var objA = A.CreateNewA() instead of var objA = new A().
```

The A.CreateNewA() would it make the code more readability. The draw back of this is I have to create a static method called CreateNewA.

Comment: What you are describing is a factory method. But honestly: What makes you think that this will make the code more readable? As you already stated, you have to write more code and therefore you have to read more code. Next thing is, every object has to have such a static method regarding to your argumentation...

Comment: I think the static method you created in class will not make the code more readable , so the first options is better and you can write less code.

Comment: True... Oh coz I have a Thrift Struct which mapped with some data object in my other code so if I named  CreateA for doing a mapping then when I read it I will know it's not create a new copy of object A even though internally is creating an object A. If I named CreateNewA then when I read it, it explicitly saying creating a new A object.

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the beholder (That was a great game!). I prefer a defined language statement like `new A` where everybody who knows the language knows exactly what will happen over a function where I have to lookup the API description to see what is doing. Of course, if flexibility or hiding details is what you want, e.g. because your factory function does something the user shouldn't bother with, it is the better option.

Comment: Code design is fun but hard. Sound like I will stick with the first one.

Comment: Static factory methods have their place.  In some cases, especially when you have a lot of overloaded constructors, they make the class API more usable.  Here is a link to a great example where static factory methods prove more readable than constructor overloading: https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2012/12/26/static-factory-methods-vs-traditional-constructors/

Answer (score 0):

I think that A.CreateNewA() is no need.

Using "new" keyword to create a new instance is more readable and easier to understand.

Using "new" keyword also allow us to pass initial value to constructor class too, e.g.,

```
const studentA = new Student('firstname', 'lastname')
```

Comment: You can also pass arguments to the static method that are then passed to the constructor.

Comment: @FrankPuffer, I mean the static method is not needed.
just "new Class(params..)" already make sense for all developers

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned in the comments, what you show in you second code sample is a well-known design pattern called "Factory Method".

In your specific example it does not have any significant benefits over directly calling the constructor with `new`. You still need a constructor, you just call it inside the static method and you can make it private.

Factory methods do make sense if you don't know the class of your object to be created at compile time. Unlike a constructor, the factory method can not only return objects of class `A` but also objects of any class derived from `A`.

The main reason for using factory methods is to separate object creation from the rest of program logic, which is beneficial for separation of concerns. Of course it comes at the cost of having to write (and read) additional code.